# d3: use svg:linearGradient for smooth "clipping" of own svg:image

Tags: svg, d3.js

In my d3 visualization I want to use a svg:linearGradient to "clip" my own appended svg:image smoothly. When I append the linear gradient to a text it works! When I append it to my own svg:image it doesn't.

This is how I draw my linearGradient:

```
g.append('svg:linearGradient')
    .attr('gradientUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('x1', function (d) { ... })
    .attr('x2', function (d) { ... })
    .attr('y1', function (d) { ... })
    .attr('y2', function (d) { ... })
    .attr('id', function (d) { return 'clip-' + d.id })
    .call(function (gradient) { getComputedGradient(gradient); });
```

When I append it to my text it works:

```
g.append('text')
    .style('fill', function (d) { return 'url(#clip-' + d.id + ')'; })
    .text(function (d) { return d.text); })
    .attr('x', function (d) { ... })
    .attr('y', function (d) { ... });
```

When I append it to my own svg it doesn't work:

```
g.append('svg:image')
    .style('fill', function (d) { return 'url(#clip-' + d.id + ')'; })
    .attr('xlink:href', '/img/test.svg');
    .attr('width', function (d) { ... })
    .attr('height', function (d) { ... })
    .attr('x', function (d) { ... })
    .attr('y', function (d) { ... });
```

The x,y,height,width attributes here are different from mine, but that can't be the reason. 
I also tried the same with a clipPath instead of a linearGradient and it works. Why doesn't the linearGradient work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[‘linearGradient’ elements are never rendered directly](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradientElement); their only usage is as something that can be referenced using the [‘fill’](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperty) and ‘stroke’ properties.

And the fill property says it applies to text and [shapes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermShape).

Since an image is neither text nor a shape, a linearGradient does not apply to it.

Comment: I tried everything: objectBoundingBox or userSpaceOnUse with different x1,y1,x2,y2 settings. It worked out only for the svg:text but not for the svg:image. I came up to use a svg:mask like in this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking You can append a rect for the mask like you would do it for a svg:clipPath. Then you can see the rect of the mask in the dom and apply your correct attributes for x,y,height,width. This worked for my svg:text && svg:image.